# How can I use "Form_tag" as opposed to "Form_for" in this file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby on Rails and have been helped immensely by Michael Hartl's excellent book: Ruby on Rails Tutorial. I have gotten to Chapter 8 and am now on the exercises in that chapter. I am having ( I assume a typical "newbie") problem with exercise 1.  In this exercise it is asked "1.Refactor the signin form to use form_tag in place of form_for." I have tried to searching for assistance with this in Stackoverflow, Google, Railscast, and many other "web searches" for two days now and I do not seem to find the assistance that I need to answer this problem.  The file I am trying to modify with form_tag is below:

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
     <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using Rails 3.2.3 in this application. Can anybody point me in the correct direction? Can anyone help me with this problem?  I would be most appreciative.

This is the implementation that uses form_tag:

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_tag( url: sessions_path ) do  %>

      <%= label_tag :email %>
      <%= text_field_tag :email %>

      <%= label_tag :password %>
      <%= password_field_tag :password %>

      <%= submit_tag "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using Rspec 2.9.0 and below are the failing tests:

```
describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end
```

and

```
describe "with invalid information" do
            before { click_button "Sign in" }

            it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
            it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

            describe "after visiting another page" do
              before { click_link "Home" }
              it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
            end
      end
```

and

```
describe "with valid information" do
            let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
            before do
              fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
              fill_in "Password", with: user.password
              click_button "Sign in"
            end

            it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
            it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
            it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
            it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

            describe "followed by signout" do
                    before { click_link "Sign out" }
                    it { should have_link('Sign in') }
            end
      end
```

Here's my routes file:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]


  get "users/new"

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
end
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have just completed this exercise as well, so I am by no means an expert; however, this is the code that has worked for me and passed all the tests:

../app/views/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span 6 offset 3">
    <%= form_tag sessions_path do %>

      <%= label_tag :email %>
      <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>

      <%= label_tag :password %>
      <%= password_field_tag :password %>

      <%= submit_tag "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New User?<%= link_to "Sign Up Now", signup_path %> </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also needed to change the ../app/controllers/sessions_contoller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user] = user.id
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end  
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Whilst this works, I'm not entirely sure why it does; if someone could explain why the changes in the controller are required it would be much appreciated. I know that this could be posed a s a separate question but it is closely related to OP and I'm sure we would both find it extremely useful in understanding not just how to get this to work but why it works this way. The following are the original view and controller files:

Original 'form_for' new.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the original sessions_controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end  
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: FYI, in the edited SessionsController, I was confused by `session[:user] = user.id` so I removed it and my test still passes and login succeeds.

Comment: If you look at the actual parameters hash, using form_for and form_tag create a different internal structure. When using form_for, a nested hash is created inside the parameters hash. This hash contains :email, which is why you have to use the params[:session][:email] syntax. form_tag, on the other hand does not create a session hash. You can access the email field directly with params[:email].

Answer (score 15):

I am working on the same step of the tutorial, and your question helped me finding my way.

The use of **label** and **text_field**, instead of label_tag and text_field_tag is working fine, and you don't have to change the controller code (this produce the same HTML code as with the original form_for method).

```
<%= form_tag(sessions_path) do %>
  <%= label :session, :email %>
  <%= text_field :session, :email %>

  <%= label :session, :password %>
  <%= password_field :session, :password %>

  <%= submit_tag("Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary") %>
<% end %>
```

You can read details in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects

Answer (score 2):

The RoR guides go over how form_tag works.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Thank you DVG.  I had "stumbled" opon that this morning. After trying out several examples listed on that page (without success) I assumed that either I don't understand what the problem is, or it didn't apply to my case.

Comment: Might I suggest showing your failing implementation using form_tag and what problems you are specifically having?

Comment: DVG, The problem that I am having is with my test suit.  When I leave the code as about all my tests pass.  When I substitute the form_tag I have 10 tests failing.  All test fail due to "ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}" Due to the fact that this is a refactoring this of course shouldn't be happening.  How do I show my failing implementation in a comment?  Thanks. @DVG

Comment: Just add it to the op, along with an example of a failing test

Comment: <% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
    <h1>Sign in</h1>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6 offset3">
       <%= form_tag(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

          <%= f.label_tag :email %>
          <%= f.text_field_tag :email %>

          <%= f.label_tag :password %>
          <%= f.password_field_tag :password %>

          <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>

        <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: Try dropping the :session. I think form_tag only takes a url

Comment: Ok tried dropping the :session from the impelementation.  No I get the error "ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `label_tag' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Okay, now you should just have to drop the block argument `|f|` and replace the tag helpers as appropriate without the f.

Comment: I dropped the block argument |f| and replaced the tag helpers as outlined above.  I now only have 8 errors in my test suit.  All 8 errors are "ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/sessions/new". I have included my routes.rb file above. At least we have made a little progress.

Comment: Is this homebrewed authentication or are you using a plugin?

Comment: I am using Ruby on Rails Tutorial [link](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) for all coding.  This is as the book states that it should be done.

Comment: Perhaps my answer was somewhat misleading.  What I meant to say was that I am following the Book [Ruby on Rails Tutorial.]http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=3.2#top) So, I would say that this is homebrewed.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Session_Helper that you aren't using in your implementation.

EDIT your helper methods.

```
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def sign_out
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    session[:user_id] = nil    
  end
```

Then you can simply use the appropriate methods in your session controller. This is a neater implementation that follows the modular approach to design. There also seems to be issues with rspec.

```
describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
```

Even though everything is correct when you visit the page these tests are flagged. My guess is that you need to change `before do` because if it was doing what you want it to do the tests would pass.

Anyways, I'm curious to what the problem is with rspec if anyone has an idea!

I think that problem is with `user.email.upcase`. You don't need `.upcase`, when you remove it tests will pass.

Answer (score 1):

I got caught not naming the the fields right. When you view source of the original, it shows you the naming scheme.

```
<%= form_tag(sessions_path) do %>

  <%= label_tag 'session_email', 'Email' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'session[email]' %>

  <%= label_tag 'session_password', 'Password' %>
  <%= password_field_tag 'session[password]' %>

  <%= submit_tag "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end -%>
```